# HTTPS requests to embedded Jetty failing

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, ssl-certificate, embedded-jetty

> **Edit:**   This is actually not a Jetty issue at all. I tried running the server using HTTPS with a self-signed certificate, and it works
>   fine. So, it's an issue getting the certificate working. I'm gonna
>   vote to close this question.

I'm trying to setup a secure site using SSL with embedded Jetty (v9.2.3). While I've been developing the site, in addition to testing locally, I've also had a live demo on the server available for others to see, running on port 8080 over HTTP.

I'm trying to switch to HTTPS now, but it won't work. The site starts up fine according to the logs, and apparently it's listening on port 443, but all requests are rejected immediately. Chrome tells me the webpage is unavailable. But there's nothing on the server to indicate an error. There's no output from either the terminal that the server is launched from or the logs. If I switch back to using port 8080 with HTTP, then it serves requests normally.

The `keystore` that's used in the launch code below has been generated using a certificate issued by a Certificate Authority (`server.crt`) with the following:

```
keytool -keystore keystore -import -alias keyalias -file server.crt -trustcacerts
```

I should also mention that when I run the server on localhost with a self-signed certificate, it works. But if the SSL keystore is the problem, then should I not be seeing an error when a request is made or when the server starts up?

Here's my launch code:

```
    // Java 7 bug (feature?) - this disables SNI everywhere...
    // required or else outgoing HTTPS requests will fail
    System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");

    PropertyConfigurator.configure("./log4j.properties");
    Server server = new Server();

    WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
    webapp.setContextPath("/");
    webapp.setWar("war");
    server.setHandler(webapp);

    HttpConfiguration https = new HttpConfiguration();
    https.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());

    SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath("keystore.jks");
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("password");
    sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("password");

    ServerConnector sslConnector = new ServerConnector(server,
            new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, "http/1.1"),
            new HttpConnectionFactory(https));
    sslConnector.setPort(port);

    server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { sslConnector });

    try {
        LOG.info("Starting server on port " + port);
        server.start();
        server.join();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.fatal("The web server has crashed", e);
    }
```

...and the server starts with the following output:

```
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @202ms
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.2.3.v20140905
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor - NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@37132aca{/,file:/home/ubuntu/CS4L/war/,AVAILABLE}{war}
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector - Started ServerConnector@261bf0a0{SSL-http/1.1}{0.0.0.0:443}
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @5792ms
```

**Edit:**
My server is running on an AWS EC2 instance and there are inbound request filters, but *all* requests coming in at ports 80 and 443 are allowed.

Comment: I have a very similar issue. While being able to connect to the server via HTTPS from various Linux, Windows XP and MacOS machines (and even Android 5.x devices) using Chrome, it is not possible to connect to the server from Windows 7 and 8 machines using Chrome. It looks like a HTTPS handshake does not completer successfully. Did you solve your problem and what was the cause?

Comment: Just in case the reported problem is still an issue for you, this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093816/chrome-under-windows-7-and-8-cannot-connect-to-embedded-jetty-9-2-x-over-https/30114837 potentially might be of value.

Comment: I actually have this working now, but I'm sorry, I just don't remember what solved the issue. I wish I'd updated this question at the time, because it's bugging me now. My server launch code is the same as I originally posted, except that I added `https.setSecurePort(port)` after the `HttpConfiguration` object initialization. Maybe it was just an issue with the common name in the cert though. If there's anything I can check for you, let me know.

Comment: Thank you. It is working now for me too (:

Comment: Cool, was it the setSecurePort call that fixed it?

Comment: Nope, the Common Name as reflected in my answer to the referenced question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and the reason was that certificate has different password than password set to keystore. They both have to be the same.